# Download (all) files via FTP with explicit TLS/SSL encryption

Tags: ssl, encryption, ftp, debian

I've been trying to download files from FTP with explicit TLS/SSL encryption from one server to another using Debian. I tried a lot of commands like `ftp` and `wget` but none of them worked and said `Login is incorrect`. I searched whole Stack Overflow and Google.

I tried `ftp` and `wget` like this:

`wget -m --user=username --password=password ftp://ip`

and

`ftp user@ip`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you figure it out? I have the request.

Comment: Nope, I disabled the encryption and then enabled it back again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wget must be version 1.18 or above. The following was tested on 1.19.1

```
wget -r --level=5 -m --no-remove-listing --reject "index.html" -c --progress=dot -N --secure-protocol=auto --no-proxy --no-passive-ftp --ftp-user=XXXXX --ftp-password=YYYYY --no-check-certificate ftps://ZZZZZZZZ.com:21
```

Here is the link on how to build wget http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.1/basicnet/wget.html